# istio sidecar injection not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have installed istio in my k8s cluster, and labeled my desired namespace with

```
istio-injection=enabled
```

However, when I install a pod, it doesn't inject the sidecar.

I followed the instructions on this page: https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/#automatic-sidecar-injection-fails-if-the-kubernetes-api-server-has-proxy-settings

and I see that my webhook namespaceSelectors are incorrect:

```
$ kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfiguration istio-sidecar-injector -o yaml | grep "namespaceSelector:" -A5
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
--
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
--
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
--
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
  objectSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio.io/deactivated: never-match
```

According to that page, they should be:

```
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      istio-injection: enabled
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - ""
```

Why are the webhook namespace selectors being installed incorrectly? I have wiped the installation and tried again, but after reinstallation the webhook selectors are always wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any hint. I installed istio via helm chart v1.17.1